# JQuery.ajax will not recognize JSON response from JSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to write a simple application using JSP's, Jquery, and AJAX to get and display data on a page.

Here is my ajax function:

```
    $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"interface_load_status_page.jsp",
                data:dataString,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    $("#response").html("");
                    $("#response").append(data);
                },
            });
```

That ajax call works properly as long as the dataType is set to "text". Unfortunately I need it to work when it is set to json. 
Here is the code for the JSP called by the ajax function

```
<%
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            String date = request.getParameter("date");
            System.out.println("Date: "+date);  
        if (date != null) {
                DBAccess acc = new DBAccess();
                ArrayList<InterfaceLoadStatus> loadStatus = acc
                        .loadStatusQuery(date);
                //System.out.println(loadStatus);
                out.println(Utils.getJSONLoadStatus(loadStatus));
            }
        %>
```

What that JSP does is take the results of a query to an oracle database and convert it to JSON format like so:

```
{"success":true,"interfaceloadstatus":[{"bType":"COC","start":"2013-04-22 03:30:10.0","end":"2013-04-22 04:35:38.0","exe":"01:05:28","handOff":"Y"},{"bType":"DST","start":"2013-04-22 00:10:09.0","end":"2013-04-22 00:23:17.0","exe":"00:13:08","handOff":"Y"},{"bType":"HTL","start":"2013-04-22 00:10:10.0","end":"2013-04-22 01:17:14.0","exe":"01:07:04","handOff":"Y"},{"bType":"RC","start":"2013-04-22 00:10:11.0","end":"2013-04-22 00:45:17.0","exe":"00:35:06","handOff":"Y"},{"bType":"AIR","start":"2013-04-22 03:00:16.0","end":"2013-04-22 04:03:58.0","exe":"01:04:42","handOff":"Y"},{"bType":"VP","start":"2013-04-22 03:00:16.0","end":"2013-04-22 04:03:58.0","exe":"01:04:42","handOff":"Y"},{"bType":"AIR-IAR","start":"2013-04-22 09:45:06.0","end":"2013-04-22 10:24:51.0","exe":"00:40:45","handOff":"Y"}]}
```

Ok so now the JSON output is fixed but still the JQuery ajax function does not recognize it

Comment: Your output is not a valid JSON. use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON

Comment: Yes, that isn't valid JSON. Each of those lines is a valid JSON object, but not the output collectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line is valid JSON, according to www.jsonlint.com. On the other hand is not the entire output valid json so if you are not feeding it line by line it might be the reason.

Comment: Ok that helps. So does that mean I have to make a seperate ajax call for each line?

Comment: That could help. Or is there any othe way you could format the Jsom like. Consider this, which is valid Json: `{
    "item1": {
        "bType": "COC",
        "start": "2013-04-22 03:30:10.0",
        "end": "2013-04-22 04:35:38.0",
        "exe": "01:05:28",
        "handOff": "Y"
    },
    "item2": {
        "bType": "DST",
        "start": "2013-04-22 00:10:09.0",
        "end": "2013-04-22 00:23:17.0",
        "exe": "00:13:08",
        "handOff": "Y"
    }
}`

Comment: Yeah I think I could try and modify what I have to come out like that! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and you've probably long since forgotten about it but I just ran into the same problem so I thought I'd share what I did incase someone else is looking for a solution.

Just keep the jsp page content type as text. But when you get the data from the response use JSON.parse().

Something like this:

JSP

```
<%@ page contentType="text" %>

*JSON here*
```

JS

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question considering his dataType is set to json. You can read further about dataTypes in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ From the selected answer he was providing an invalid json object.